# print HTML using php_printer.dll

Tags: php

I want to print using php_printer.dll. I have no problem printing a simple text but it doesn't print HTML file and it prints the tags like :

<-h-t-m-l->
    <-b-o-d-y->
        test
    <-/-b-o-d-y->
<-/-h-t-m-l->

I don't have any choice other than using php_printer.dll .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php_printer.dll does not contain any HTML rendering features, so you can't do what you are trying to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Firefox commandline print extension from [here](https://sites.google.com/site/torisugari/commandlineprint2)? It might not be the best, but it will definitely print your html for you. It works for my needs just fine.